# Apache Phoenix select with joins execution plan

Tags: hbase, sql-execution-plan, apache-phoenix

I have a simple query with two joins that I'm running using apache phoenix driver (v4.13.1):

```
explain 
   select one.pk, two.pk, three.pk
   from table_one one
      left join table_two two on two.pk = one.two_id
      left join table_three three on three.pk = two.three_id . 
   where one.pk = 1
```

The result looks quite bad:

```
CLIENT 1-CHUNK 1 ROWS 384 BYTES PARALLEL 1-WAY ROUND ROBIN POINT LOOKUP ON 1 KEY OVER table_one
    PARALLEL LEFT-JOIN TABLE 0
        CLIENT 1-CHUNK PARALLEL 1-WAY ROUND ROBIN FULL SCAN OVER table_two
    PARALLEL LEFT-JOIN TABLE 1(DELAYED EVALUATION)
        CLIENT 1-CHUNK PARALLEL 1-WAY ROUND ROBIN FULL SCAN OVER table_three
            SERVER FILTER BY FIRST KEY ONLY
```

Notice that joins on table_two and table_three are going to be FULL SCANs according to the plan, even though joins are made by rowkey.

I would expect RANGE SCANs or at least not a FULL SCAN here. Do I understand this plan correctly? Is FULL SCAN really what will end up being executed?